# Save object variables at some point and reuse them exactly as they were saved?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an object of type Player which has health, position and color variables.

The game goes through several stages and all variables change during this stages. For example:

- Stage1 the player has 80 health, 50.3f position, and green color.
- Stage2 the player has 50 health, 90f position, and blue color.

In stage 3 I would like to choose the exact same copy of Stage1 or Stage2 variables (at random).

One way I could do this is that in each stage I assign these variables to another Player object like

```
stage1PlayerSaved.health = 80;
stage1PlayerSaved.position = 50.3f;
stage1PlayerSaved.color = Color.Green;
```

And the same I would do for Stage2 and then reuse one of these objects in Stage3. But what if I have a lot of variables to save? For example, in addition to those 3 I would have more than 20, 30. The process of saving each variable is ugly.

Is there any other (easier) approach to save and then reuse the variables I need at certain stages? For example, saving a copy of object at the exact stage and then just reuse its variables later when needed?

Comment: If you want to save an in-memory copy, [create a Copy-Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor) for making a copy of the object and keep the copies in a list or dictionary or some other collection.

Comment: Another option would be to serialize (e.g. to JSON) and deserialize. Not ideal in terms of performance, but maybe sufficient for you.

Comment: what about saving the state of the Player by serializing the object to Json?string serializedPlayer = JSonConvert.SerializeObject(player1);

Comment: You could store the information in a struct. This way you bundle the variables into one variable. It will copy the information when assigning it to an other variable.

Comment: you want object state to be saved after both stage, then you have to store them. Either in memory or on disk. if number of players goes big, you can optimise information which is going to be saved (like not saving unwanted info which is not going to change - eg. name).

Answer (score 1):

to copy an object you can either use concept of [copy constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor) or you can use [Cloning](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/icloneable-interface-in-c-sharp1).

but as you mentioned in question that number of player may go high, I would recommended you to store only those information which is going to be changed over stages (exclude not changing information from saving)

you code should look somewhat similar to this,

Suppose you have `Player` class then you should also have `PlayerInfo` class too,  for e.g.

```
public class Player
{
public int PId;     //This will not change
public string Name; //This will not change
public int Energy;  //This may change over stanges

//you should have a method which returns PlayerInfo object
public PlayerInfo GetPlayerInfoToBeStored()
{
    return new PlayerInfo(this.Energy);
}
}

//this class will have only those information which can change
public class PlayerInfo
{
public int Energy;

public PlayerInfo(int playerEnergey)
{
    Energy = playerEnergey;
}
}
```

and while actual using can be like this,

you can have a gloable Dictionary

```
public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, PlayerInfo>> StoredPlayerState = 
    new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, PlayerInfo>>();
```

and a method to add infromation in it.

```
public void SavePlayerInfo(int stageNum, List<Player> playerList)
{
    Dictionary<int, PlayerInfo> playerInfoTable = new Dictionary<int, PlayerInfo>();
    foreach(Player player in playerList)
    {
        playerInfoTable.Add( player.PId, player.GetPlayerInfoToBeStored());
        StoredPlayerState.Add(stageNum, playerInfoTable);
    }
}
```

and one method to set current player with previously set value

```
public void ResetPlayerWithOldValues(int stageNum, List<Player> originalPlayerList)
{
    if (StoredPlayerState.ContainsKey(stageNum))
    {
        foreach(Player originalPlayer in originalPlayerList)
        {
            if (StoredPlayerState[stageNum].ContainsKey(originalPlayer.PId))
            {
                PlayerInfo playerInfo = StoredPlayerState[stageNum][originalPlayer.PId];
                originalPlayer.Energy = playerInfo.Energy;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now using this flow will be too much easy,

```
public void MainMethod()
{
    List<Player> playerList = new List<Player>();
    //add players in this list

    //after stage 1
    SavePlayerInfo(1, playerList);

    //after stage 2
    SavePlayerInfo(2, playerList);

    //At stage 3 :setting current players with any of those two state's values
    ResetPlayerWithOldValues(randomStageNum, playerList);

    //and simply keep using playerList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I develop games, I usually create a singleton to store global game variables that I want to keep or update through out the different scenes, If I understood you correctly, this may help you:

```
public class PlayerState
{
    public int PlayerHealth { get; set; }
    public float PlayerPosition { get; set; }
}
```

This is the singleton:

```
public sealed class GameVariables 
{
    private static readonly _instance = new GameVariables();

    public static GameVariables Intance { get { return _instance; } }

    private GameVariables()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
       //Initialize your variables here when you start a new game
       TotalScore = 0;

       PlayerStates = new Dictionary<int, PlayerState>();
       [...]
    }

    public Dictionary<int, PlayerState> PlayerStates { get; private set; }
    public int TotalScore { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

Then during the game just initialize player state and get the instance whenever you need it:

```
public class Scene3
{
    void Start()
    {
        GameVariables.Instance.PlayerStates.Add(3, new PlayerState());
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        //Get player state for scene 1
        PlayerState playerStateScene1 = GameVariables.Instance.PlayerStates[1];

        //Get player state for scene 2
        PlayerState playerStateScene2 = GameVariables.Instance.PlayerStates[2];

        //Update player state for this scene
        GameVariables.Instance.PlayerStates[3].PlayerHealth = 80;
        GameVariables.Instance.PlayerStates[3].TotalScore += 100;
        [...]
    }
}
```

Don't forget to reset the game if you start again from the main menu:

```
public class MainMenu
{
     void Play()
     {
         GameVariables.Instance.Reset();
     }
}
```